# Как посчитать предельные размеры квадратной матрицы, которую можно перемножить на 8 гб оперативной памяти?

Tags: c++, c

Как посчитать предельные размеры квадратной матрицы, которую можно перемножить на 8 гб оперативной памяти? Тип double.

Comment: перемножить с чем?

Comment: матрица на матрицу, DGEMM

Comment: Ну мало ли... Вдруг у вас матрица может в памяти не располагаться, например, хитрая матрица, в которой `m[i][j] == i+j`? :) А так, по порядку величины... Нужны 2 исходные матрицы и одна результирующая — 3*N^2*8 = 24*N^2 байт. Приравняем в 8Г, получается что-то порядка N ~ 18900.

Comment: В современных операционках количество памяти влияет только на скорость. А чтобы определить возможность, нужно смотреть в настройках операционной системы, сколько вам можно получить размер памяти.

Comment: Не обязательно запихивать в память сразу всё целиком, поэтому ограничений не существует. См. тж. https://habr.com/ru/post/359272/